# Pyinstaller exe fails to execute numpy operation when run from command prompt but works fine from the conda env in anaconda prompt

Tags: numpy, windows-10, python-3.6, exe, pyinstaller

The exe generated using pyinstaller runs fine in the conda environment. However, when run via command prompt it runs only upto a point in the code. Using multiple print statements, I found that the exe is stuck at a numpy operation and stops with ***.exe has stopped working*** error.

The same is reproduced with a smaller problem for this post.

The entry point script is:

```
import numpy
from app.__main__ import main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The main code inside the 'app' folder:

```
import numpy 
def main():
    rand1 = numpy.random.rand(3,3)
    rand2 = numpy.random.rand(3,3)
    
    print('Before numpy.dot() operation') # The exe stops at this point

    mat1 = numpy.matmul(rand1, rand2)

    print(mat1)
```

The output in the warn-cli.txt file is:

```
This file lists modules PyInstaller was not able to find. This does not
necessarily mean this module is required for running you program. Python and
Python 3rd-party packages include a lot of conditional or optional modules. For
example the module 'ntpath' only exists on Windows, whereas the module
'posixpath' only exists on Posix systems.

Types if import:
* top-level: imported at the top-level - look at these first
* conditional: imported within an if-statement
* delayed: imported from within a function
* optional: imported within a try-except-statement

IMPORTANT: Do NOT post this list to the issue-tracker. Use it as a basis for
           yourself tracking down the missing module. Thanks!

missing module named 'org.python' - imported by copy (optional), xml.sax (delayed, conditional), setuptools.sandbox (conditional)
missing module named _scproxy - imported by urllib.request (conditional)
missing module named termios - imported by tty (top-level), getpass (optional), psutil._compat (delayed, optional)
missing module named pwd - imported by posixpath (delayed, conditional), shutil (optional), tarfile (optional), http.server (delayed, optional), webbrowser (delayed), pathlib (delayed, conditional, optional), distutils.util (delayed, conditional), distutils.archive_util (optional), netrc (delayed, conditional), getpass (delayed), psutil (optional)
missing module named _dummy_threading - imported by dummy_threading (optional)
missing module named urllib.pathname2url - imported by urllib (conditional), PyInstaller.lib.modulegraph._compat (conditional)
missing module named 'java.lang' - imported by platform (delayed, optional), xml.sax._exceptions (conditional)
missing module named multiprocessing.get_context - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.pool (top-level), multiprocessing.managers (top-level), multiprocessing.sharedctypes (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.TimeoutError - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.pool (top-level)
missing module named grp - imported by shutil (optional), tarfile (optional), pathlib (delayed), distutils.archive_util (optional)
missing module named vms_lib - imported by platform (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named java - imported by platform (delayed)
missing module named _winreg - imported by platform (delayed, optional), numpy.distutils.cpuinfo (delayed, conditional, optional), pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs (delayed, conditional)
missing module named _frozen_importlib_external - imported by importlib._bootstrap (delayed), importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional)
excluded module named _frozen_importlib - imported by importlib (optional), importlib.abc (optional), PyInstaller.loader.pyimod02_archive (delayed)
missing module named readline - imported by cmd (delayed, conditional, optional), code (delayed, conditional, optional), pdb (delayed, optional)
missing module named org - imported by pickle (optional)
missing module named multiprocessing.BufferTooShort - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.connection (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.AuthenticationError - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.connection (top-level)
missing module named _posixsubprocess - imported by subprocess (conditional), multiprocessing.util (delayed)
missing module named multiprocessing.set_start_method - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.spawn (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.get_start_method - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), multiprocessing.spawn (top-level)
missing module named multiprocessing.SimpleQueue - imported by multiprocessing (top-level), concurrent.futures.process (top-level)
missing module named posix - imported by os (conditional, optional)
missing module named resource - imported by posix (top-level)
missing module named 'win32com.gen_py' - imported by win32com (conditional, optional), c:\users\syunary\.conda\envs\myenv36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py (top-level)
missing module named pyimod03_importers - imported by c:\users\syunary\.conda\envs\myenv36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\rthooks\pyi_rth_pkgres.py (top-level)
missing module named __builtin__ - imported by numpy.core.numerictypes (conditional), numpy.core.numeric (conditional), numpy.lib.function_base (conditional), numpy.lib._iotools (conditional), numpy.ma.core (conditional), numpy.distutils.misc_util (delayed, conditional), numpy (conditional), pkg_resources._vendor.pyparsing (conditional), setuptools._vendor.pyparsing (conditional)
missing module named ordereddict - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.pyparsing (optional), setuptools._vendor.pyparsing (optional)
missing module named StringIO - imported by PyInstaller.lib.modulegraph._compat (conditional), PyInstaller.lib.modulegraph.zipio (conditional), setuptools._vendor.six (conditional), numpy.lib.utils (delayed, conditional), numpy.lib.format (delayed, conditional), numpy.testing._private.utils (conditional), pkg_resources._vendor.six (conditional)
missing module named 'pkg_resources.extern.pyparsing' - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.packaging.requirements (top-level), pkg_resources._vendor.packaging.markers (top-level)
missing module named 'com.sun' - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named com - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs (delayed)
missing module named pkg_resources.extern.packaging - imported by pkg_resources.extern (top-level), pkg_resources (top-level)
missing module named pkg_resources.extern.appdirs - imported by pkg_resources.extern (top-level), pkg_resources (top-level)
missing module named 'pkg_resources.extern.six.moves' - imported by pkg_resources (top-level), pkg_resources._vendor.packaging.requirements (top-level)
missing module named pkg_resources.extern.six - imported by pkg_resources.extern (top-level), pkg_resources (top-level)
missing module named commands - imported by numpy.distutils.cpuinfo (conditional)
missing module named setuptools.extern.packaging - imported by setuptools.extern (top-level), setuptools.dist (top-level), setuptools.command.egg_info (top-level)
missing module named 'setuptools.extern.six' - imported by setuptools (top-level), setuptools.extension (top-level)
missing module named 'setuptools.extern.packaging.specifiers' - imported by setuptools.config (top-level)
missing module named 'setuptools.extern.packaging.version' - imported by setuptools.config (top-level), setuptools.msvc (top-level)
missing module named setuptools.extern.six.moves.filterfalse - imported by setuptools.extern.six.moves (top-level), setuptools.dist (top-level), setuptools.msvc (top-level)
missing module named setuptools.extern.six.moves.filter - imported by setuptools.extern.six.moves (top-level), setuptools.dist (top-level), setuptools.ssl_support (top-level), setuptools.command.py36compat (top-level)
missing module named setuptools.extern.ordered_set - imported by setuptools.extern (top-level), setuptools.dist (top-level), setuptools.command.sdist (top-level)
missing module named 'setuptools.extern.packaging.utils' - imported by setuptools.wheel (top-level)
missing module named 'setuptools.extern.packaging.tags' - imported by setuptools.wheel (top-level)
missing module named 'backports.ssl_match_hostname' - imported by setuptools.ssl_support (optional)
missing module named backports - imported by setuptools.ssl_support (optional)
missing module named 'setuptools._vendor.six.moves' - imported by 'setuptools._vendor.six.moves' (top-level)
missing module named 'setuptools.extern.pyparsing' - imported by setuptools._vendor.packaging.requirements (top-level), setuptools._vendor.packaging.markers (top-level)
missing module named _manylinux - imported by setuptools._vendor.packaging.tags (delayed, optional)
missing module named setuptools.extern.six.moves.map - imported by setuptools.extern.six.moves (top-level), setuptools.dist (top-level), setuptools.command.easy_install (top-level), setuptools.sandbox (top-level), setuptools.package_index (top-level), setuptools.ssl_support (top-level), setuptools.command.egg_info (top-level), setuptools.namespaces (top-level)
runtime module named setuptools.extern.six.moves - imported by setuptools.dist (top-level), configparser (top-level), setuptools.command.easy_install (top-level), setuptools.sandbox (top-level), setuptools.command.setopt (top-level), setuptools.package_index (top-level), setuptools.ssl_support (top-level), setuptools.py33compat (top-level), setuptools.command.egg_info (top-level), setuptools.command.py36compat (top-level), setuptools.namespaces (top-level), setuptools.msvc (top-level), 'setuptools._vendor.six.moves' (top-level)
missing module named setuptools.extern.six - imported by setuptools.extern (top-level), setuptools.monkey (top-level), setuptools.dist (top-level), setuptools.extern.six.moves (top-level), setuptools.config (top-level), setuptools.command.easy_install (top-level), setuptools.sandbox (top-level), setuptools.py27compat (top-level), setuptools.package_index (top-level), setuptools.py33compat (top-level), setuptools.wheel (top-level), setuptools.command.egg_info (top-level), setuptools.command.sdist (top-level), setuptools.command.bdist_egg (top-level), setuptools.unicode_utils (top-level), setuptools.installer (top-level), setuptools.command.develop (top-level)
missing module named 'numpy_distutils.cpuinfo' - imported by numpy.f2py.diagnose (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named 'numpy_distutils.fcompiler' - imported by numpy.f2py.diagnose (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named 'numpy_distutils.command' - imported by numpy.f2py.diagnose (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named numpy_distutils - imported by numpy.f2py.diagnose (delayed, optional)
missing module named __svn_version__ - imported by numpy.f2py.__version__ (optional)
missing module named numarray - imported by numpy.distutils.system_info (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named Numeric - imported by numpy.distutils.system_info (delayed, conditional, optional)
missing module named ConfigParser - imported by numpy.distutils.system_info (conditional), numpy.distutils.npy_pkg_config (conditional)
missing module named _curses - imported by curses (top-level), curses.has_key (top-level)
missing module named pytest - imported by numpy._pytesttester (delayed), scipy._lib._testutils (delayed)
missing module named 'nose.plugins' - imported by numpy.testing._private.noseclasses (top-level), numpy.testing._private.nosetester (delayed)
missing module named uarray - imported by scipy._lib.uarray (conditional, optional)
missing module named psutil._psutil_aix - imported by psutil (top-level), psutil._psaix (top-level)
missing module named psutil._psutil_sunos - imported by psutil (top-level), psutil._pssunos (top-level)
missing module named psutil._psutil_bsd - imported by psutil (top-level), psutil._psbsd (top-level)
missing module named psutil._psutil_osx - imported by psutil (top-level), psutil._psosx (top-level)
missing module named _psutil_linux - imported by psutil (conditional)
missing module named psutil._psutil_posix - imported by psutil (top-level), psutil._pslinux (top-level), psutil._psosx (top-level), psutil._psbsd (top-level), psutil._pssunos (top-level), psutil._psaix (top-level)
missing module named fcntl - imported by psutil._compat (delayed, optional)
missing module named dummy_thread - imported by numpy.core.arrayprint (conditional, optional), cffi.lock (conditional, optional)
missing module named thread - imported by numpy.core.arrayprint (conditional, optional), cffi.lock (conditional, optional), cffi.cparser (conditional, optional)
missing module named cStringIO - imported by cPickle (top-level), cffi.ffiplatform (optional)
missing module named copy_reg - imported by numpy.core (conditional), cPickle (top-level), cStringIO (top-level)
missing module named cPickle - imported by pycparser.ply.yacc (delayed, optional)
missing module named cffi._pycparser - imported by cffi (optional), cffi.cparser (optional)
missing module named numpy.random.randn - imported by numpy.random (top-level), scipy (top-level)
missing module named numpy.random.rand - imported by numpy.random (top-level), scipy (top-level)
missing module named 'nose.util' - imported by numpy.testing._private.noseclasses (top-level)
missing module named nose - imported by numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed, optional), numpy.testing._private.decorators (delayed), numpy.testing._private.noseclasses (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.number - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.signbit - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.float64 - imported by numpy.core (delayed), numpy.testing._private.utils (delayed)
missing module named numpy.core.float32 - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.intp - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.testing._private.utils (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.lib.i0 - imported by numpy.lib (top-level), numpy.dual (top-level)
missing module named cpickle - imported by numpy.compat.py3k (conditional)
missing module named pickle5 - imported by numpy.compat.py3k (conditional, optional)
missing module named numpy.core.integer - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.fft.helper (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.sqrt - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level), numpy.fft._pocketfft (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.conjugate - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.fft._pocketfft (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.sign - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.divide - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.object_ - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.geterrobj - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.add - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.complexfloating - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.inexact - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.cdouble - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.csingle - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.double - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named numpy.core.single - imported by numpy.core (top-level), numpy.linalg.linalg (top-level)
missing module named future_builtins - imported by numpy.lib.npyio (conditional)
missing module named urllib2 - imported by numpy.lib._datasource (delayed, conditional)
missing module named urlparse - imported by numpy.lib._datasource (delayed, conditional)
missing module named numpy.recarray - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level)
missing module named numpy.dtype - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level), numpy.ctypeslib (top-level)
missing module named numpy.expand_dims - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level)
missing module named numpy.array - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level), numpy.ma.extras (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level), numpy.ctypeslib (top-level)
missing module named numpy.bool_ - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level)
missing module named numpy.iscomplexobj - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level)
missing module named numpy.amin - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level)
missing module named numpy.amax - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level)
missing module named numpy.ndarray - imported by numpy (top-level), numpy.ma.core (top-level), numpy.ma.extras (top-level), numpy.ma.mrecords (top-level), numpy.ctypeslib (top-level)
missing module named numpy.histogramdd - imported by numpy (delayed), numpy.lib.twodim_base (delayed)
missing module named numpy.eye - imported by numpy (delayed), numpy.core.numeric (delayed)
```

I am using: 
Windows 10
python=3.6.10
pyinstaller=3.6
numpy=1.18.5

I've also tried with the latest *pyinstaller development* version and a lower version of numpy but the problem persists.

**Edit**
The lower version of numpy tried was 1.17

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved.
Downgrading numpyt to 1.13 worked.
Earlier I had downgraded numpy to only 1.17 which didn't work.

I tried the problem in my linux PC where it worked. So I created an env with same package version as in linux.

I guess pyinstaller3.6 doesn't support latest versions of numpy.